# How are CPU rankings determined in Mario Kart 8?

Tags: mario-kart-8, mario-kart-8-deluxe

When playing races offline in *Mario Kart 8* and *Mario Kart 8 Deluxe*, there can be up to 11 computer-controlled players in a game. After all human players have reached the finish line, the CPUs are put in a list of which ones were in which place. How is this determined? Does it order them by their place when all players reached the finish line, or does the game do something like simulate the rest of the race to determine when each character ended up finishing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the last human player finishes, the remainder of the CPUs are placed based on their current position. No simulation or situational calculation is done; the game only pays attention to the CPUs' location on the track.

(Previous games extrapolated finish time as well. I don't think MK8 cares about finish time.)